# Issue with Scrolling Text Selection in Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently facing an issue with scrolling text selection in a `TextFormField`. I have a custom `TextAreaFormField` widget with a fixed height and a `ScrollView` for handling longer texts. However, when I select and move the text, the selection can go outside the text field's border and become hidden.

[video](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8849ljxze8pjxg27eclnb/15.08.2023-15-29-17.mp4?dl=0&rlkey=jl4g6jszrbz2awwjjfgb1mwfd)

The issue arises when I select and move the text within the TextFormField. The text selection can go out of the visible area, and I need the TextFormField to scroll appropriately to keep the selected text within the visible region.

How to make the `TextFormField` scroll when selecting and moving text, so that the selected text remains within the visible area? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```dart
class _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? value;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final EdgeInsets scrollPadding;
  final double? height;
  final bool readOnly;

  const _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContent({
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.scrollPadding,
    required this.height,
    this.readOnly = false,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContentState createState() =>
      _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContentState();
}

class _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContentState
    extends State<_CustomTextAreaFormFieldContent> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _textController.text = widget.value ?? '';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        const Div(),
        Scrollbar(
          controller: _scrollController,
          thumbVisibility: true,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: widget.height == null ? null : widget.height! - 121,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    scrollPadding: widget.scrollPadding,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                      hintText: '',
                    ),
                    readOnly: widget.readOnly,
                    onChanged: (value) => widget.onChanged(
                      value.trim(),
                    ),
                    minLines: 6,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my Main.dart file code i have used **TextField**

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(
            scrollController: _scrollController,
            textController: _textController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  final TextEditingController textController;

  const MyWidget({
    required this.scrollController,
    required this.textController,
  }) : super();

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.scrollController.dispose();
    widget.textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        const Divider(),
        Scrollbar(
          controller: widget.scrollController,
          thumbVisibility: true,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: widget.scrollController,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: widget.textController,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black, // Set text color to black
                  ),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '', filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white, // Set background color to white
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  ),
                  minLines: 6,
                  maxLines: 8,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue of scrolling the TextFormField's content while maintaining text selection visibility, you'll need to update the scroll position in sync with the text selection changes.

```
class _CustomTextAreaFormFieldContentState
    extends State<_CustomTextAreaFormFieldContent> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final _textController = TextEditingController();
  late TextSelection _currentSelection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _textController.text = widget.value ?? '';
    _currentSelection = _textController.selection;
  }

  void _updateSelection(TextSelection newSelection) {
    setState(() {
      _currentSelection = newSelection;
    });

    
    final scrollMaxExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final visibleScrollExtent = _scrollController.position.viewportDimension;

    
    final selectionOffset = _textController.selection.extentOffset;
    final selectionRect = _textController.selection.extent;
    final selectionTopOffset = selectionRect.top;
    final selectionBottomOffset = selectionRect.bottom;

    
    if (selectionTopOffset < _scrollController.offset) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(selectionTopOffset);
    } else if (selectionBottomOffset > _scrollController.offset + visibleScrollExtent) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(selectionBottomOffset - visibleScrollExtent);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        const Div(),
        Scrollbar(
          controller: _scrollController,
          thumbVisibility: true,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: widget.height == null ? null : widget.height! - 121,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                    scrollPadding: widget.scrollPadding,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                      hintText: '',
                    ),
                    readOnly: widget.readOnly,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      widget.onChanged(value.trim());
                      _updateSelection(_textController.selection);
                    },
                    minLines: 6,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```